# SetGet для массивов

Tags: c++

Как правильно написать set и get функции для массива в C++?

Comment: Напишите подробнее, чего вы хотите добиться, какую задачу решить, чем не подходит оператор `[]`.

Comment: Допустим есть массив из 5 элементов в классе. В main функции я присвоил им значения. Как мне правильно его передать функции set а потом вытащить, например 3 элемент массива на экран. При этом надо испоьзовать get функцию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите иметь дело с массивами с любым числом элементов и типа, то вам следует написать шаблонные функции.

Ниже показано, как это сделать.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T, size_t N>
T get(const T(&a)[N], size_t i)
{
    if (N < i) throw std::out_of_range("Index out of the range");
    return a[i];
}

template <typename T, size_t N>
void set( T(&a)[N], size_t i, const T &value )
{
    if (N < i) throw std::out_of_range("Index out of the range");
    a[i] = value;
}

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    int a[N];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) set(a, i, ( int )i);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) std::cout << get(a, i) << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```